# Как дебажить typescript в VS Code

Tags: node.js, отладка, typescript, visual-studio-code

Вот с js все понятно. Можно typescript? Нужен пожалуй файл launch.json, но я не знаю как его писать. И дебажить нужно именно Typescript, а не компилить его сначала в js. И нужно чтоб можно было дебажить текущий файл, а не приписанный вручную в конфиге.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже не люблю долго настраивать среду для разработки. Обычно, я добавляю брейкпоинт в коде, используя инструкцию `debugger`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После обновления страницы с открытыми [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open) исполнение остановится на брейкпоинте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в файле tsconfig.json указать флаг компиляции "sourceMap": true, то Chrome автоматически будет показывать мэппинг исходного кода в TypeScript.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для удобства, прикладываю содержимое файла.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES3",
        "module": "amd",
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "dom"
        ],
        "typeRoots" : [
            "./types",
        ],
        "outFile": "./dist/cube.js",
        "rootDir": "./src/",
        "declaration": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
    },
    "exclude": [
        "dist/**"
    ]
}
```